# Is "World Top Education" correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is `World Top Education` grammatically correct for a section label that wants to summarize that a country's education/universities are among the bests of the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating titles for pieces of writing, you have quite a bit of freedom since the grammatical details of sentence structure don't apply. But "World Top Education" doesn't sound good to me. All three of the words seem like nouns at first glance, and the connection between them isn't obvious. When I read your explanation of what it means, it does make some sense, but a title should make immediate sense without explanation.

Although it isn't exactly what you mean (not quite as superlative), "World Class Education" sounds better and has the familiarity of the expression "World Class". We all know what that means. Rearranging the words to "Top Education in the World" communicates better, but still doesn't sound 100% idiomatic.

"World Leader in Education" or "Global Leader in Education" sound better, but they are both descriptors of the country, not the education.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is imprecise as well as awkward, if not ungrammatical.

> One of the world's best educational systems

Or

> Globally esteemed schools and universities

are possible titles that says what you mean concise and quite idiomatic.